# A question regarding definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Why when I evaluate this integral:

$$
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{1}{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x} \mathrm{d} x
$$

using my calculator in Radians I get an answer, whereas when I calculate it in Degrees like this:

$$
\int_{45}^{60} \frac{1}{\sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x} \mathrm{d} x
$$

I get a different answer?

Aren't we just finding the same difference $F(b)-F(a)$?

Comment: You can't use degrees. If you use degrees, it is no longer true (for example) that $(\sin x)' = \cos x$. You would have to introduce a substitution that involved a factor of $180/\pi$.

Comment: Why isn't $$
(\sin x)^{\prime}=\cos x
$$ in degrees?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214912/derivative-of-the-sine-function-when-the-argument-is-measured-in-degrees)

Comment: Yeah, I got it, thank you .