# Why does the TI-30X Pro calculator seem to get the derivative of $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$ wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculator

I typed the derivative of $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$ into my calculator, and it outputted $0.0174...$ I was expecting the answer $1$. What went wrong?
[image: Calculator]

Comment: Put your calculator in radians mode. The derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$ only if $x$ is measured in radians. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214912/derivative-of-the-sine-function-when-the-argument-is-measured-in-degrees) might be relevant.

Comment: @kipf ‍♂️ Of course, thanks!

Comment: @JohnDouma: That is true, but the derivative of $\sin(x^\circ)$ is not $\cos(x^\circ)$. Since angles are a dimensionless quantity, the degrees symbol is actually a shorthand for the constant $\frac{2\pi}{360}$, and so by the chain rule, the derivative of $\sin(x^\circ)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{360}\cos(x^\circ)$.

Comment: You also missed a $0$ when you typed up the answer you are getting

Comment: @RossMillikan: Sorry, that was my mistake. I edited the question to transcribe what the calculator was saying, since I thought it would make it more accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculator is in degrees mode. As such, it is calculating the derivative of the function $\sin (x^\circ)$, which is $\dfrac{2\pi}{360}\cos(x^\circ)$. At $x=0$, we have $\dfrac{2\pi}{360}\cos(x^\circ)=\dfrac{2\pi}{360}\cos 0=\dfrac{2\pi}{360}$, which agrees with the result given on the calculator.

By contrast, the derivative of the function $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, and $\cos0=1$. Therefore, if your calculator is set to radians mode, it ought to output $1$.

Comment: ‍♂️ It's not the first time that this is happening to me, thanks!

Comment: @no1dea: No problem! When I was calculus student, I ended up getting so tired of remembering whether to use degrees/radians mode, that I just stuck to radians mode, and whenever I need to work with degrees, I just wrote $x\times\frac{\pi}{180}$ instead of $x^\circ$.

Comment: I'm almost always using radians, but this calculator resets back to degrees whenever I reset the memory to clear the variables.